# How do I get the REST client using javascript?

Tags: javascript, tfs, visual-sourcesafe, node-rest-client

Visual studios has the following typescript code on their website that I was trying to follow as an example:

```
import RestClient = require("TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient");
 // Get an instance of the client
var client = RestClient.getClient();
// Call a method on the client
// e.g. client.getResource(...).then(...);
```

Part of the javascript code I have is:

```
VSS.init({
        explicitNotifyLoaded: true,
        usePlatformStyles: true
    });
  VSS.require([
      "VSS/Controls",
      "VSS/Controls/Menus",
      "VSS/Controls/Dialogs",
      "VSS/Service",
      "TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient",
      "VSS/WebApi/Contracts"],
      function (VSS_Service, TFS_Wit_WebApi) {
          //get the REST client
          var witClient = VSS_Service.getCollectionClient(TFS_Wit_WebApi.WorkItemTrackingHttpClient);
      }
  );
```

However when I do this I get an error that says that VSS_Service.getCollectionClient(TFS_Wit_WebApi.WorkItemTrackingHttpClient) is not a function.  Do I need to initialize VSS_Service other than the VSS.require(["VSS/Service"]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made witClient and outside variable so I could use it anywhere in my program, and added Controls and Grids to the function which worked.

```
var witClient;
  VSS.init({
        explicitNotifyLoaded: true,
        usePlatformScripts: true, 
        usePlatformStyles: true
    });
  VSS.require([
      "VSS/Controls", "VSS/Controls/Grids",
      "VSS/Service", "TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient"],
      function (Controls, Grids, VSS_Service, TFS_Wit_WebApi) {
          //get the REST client
          witClient = VSS_Service;//.getCollectionClient(TFS_Wit_WebApi.WorkItemTrackingHttpClient);
          witClient = witClient.getCollectionClient(TFS_Wit_WebApi.WorkItemTrackingHttpClient);
      }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your code is correct, just not use `RestClient` as a var, try to modify

```
var RestClient = VSS_Service.getCollectionClient(TFS_Wit_WebApi.WorkItemTrackingHttpClient);
```

to

```
var witClient = VSS_Service.getCollectionClient(TFS_Wit_WebApi.WorkItemTrackingHttpClient);
```

Useful article: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/get-started/node

Comment: I tried that, but it's still giving me the same error.  Do you have any other ideas or suggestions?